# java.lang.VerifyError when running main class in Eclipse

Tags: java, compiler-errors, aspectj

I am working with AspectJ and was more or less forced to install Eclipse (since I usually use NetBeans). Have installed the AspectJ plugin and created an AspectJ project, but now that I try to run the program I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 140 in method Notepad.<init>()V at offset 131
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I am completely clueless as to what I have to do. I have a Notepad class that has the main method and then an additional aspectj class.  for some reason I could run the the program before, but then I must have changed something that has to do with the environment or source etc. The program was runnable until I made some changes in the .aj aspect and saved it.

Any tips on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated as I am becoming increasingly frustrated with all the issues that keep on coming up for me trying to use AspectJ and Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's going on without seeing the program you wrote, but I can suggest a few things:

1. Are you using Java 7 to run or compile your Java code?  AspectJ on top of Java 7 is relatively new and requires a snapshot build of AspectJ.
2. Can you get your application to compile and run on the command line?
3. This could be a genuine bug in the compiler.  In which case you could post on the AspectJ mailing list or raise a bug at eclipse.org.  Both of which are closely monitored.

The fact that you see a verify error leads me to believe that this is #1.  However, a project zip would be required to give you any definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using JRE 7 to run and compile. Might be #1 then as u suggest. The Notepad (uses awt) is Oracle copyright and was provided by my teacher for this assignment, the only code I am writing is the aspect. 

I have thought about just writing the code with a regular editor and compiling/running in the command prompt, but it seems very hard and I don't know how to set it up. (already spent like 10hrs first trying to get aspectj working in Netbeans and then in Eclipse). Please excuse my ignorance, I don't really get these things.

Comment: What is a snapshot build of AspectJ?

Comment: Snapshot aspectj downloads are available here: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php  If you are going to compile on the command line, then I would use one of these.  Alternatively, you can update to a snapshot build of AJDT (AspectJ Eclipse tools).  You can use this updatet site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/dev/update Install it as you did your original build of ajdt.

Comment: Updating didn't change anything unfortunately. What are the steps to compile.aj files on the command line?

Comment: See the information here: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/command-line-tools.html#ajc-ref-top

Comment: Thank you. BTW, I recognize your name, are you a developer of AspectJ? Or where might I have come across your name?

Comment: Finally I uninstalled Java, AspectJ, Eclipse etc and then reinstalled and now it compiles and runs just fine. Thanks for the help and the great work with AJDT!